# Why scalar Date GraphQL doesn't work

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I have project where I use `graphql` and need provide date thought `graphql`, when I use `String` type date properly shows in resolver, but when I use `scalar Date` in resolver I get `false` intead date. In docs find nothing. Date provided as `Wed Jan 11 2018 21:30:00`. Should I install `moment` cause I get warning `eprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date()` and I don't use `moment` in my project.

```js
/*---- doesn't work ----*/
scalar Date
type Event {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  dateStart: Date!
  dateEnd: Date!
  users: [User]
  room: Room
}
input EventInput {
  title: String!
  dateStart: Date!
  dateEnd: Date!
}

/*---- works ----*/
type Event {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  dateStart: String!
  dateEnd: String!
  users: [User]
  room: Room
}
input EventInput {
  title: String!
  dateStart: String!
  dateEnd: String!
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to resolve custom scalar Date in your resolver

```js
Date: {
  __serialize(value) {

    return value; // value sent to the client
  },

  __parseValue(value) {

    return value;
  },
  __parseLiteral(ast) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ast)).value;
  }
}
```

Add this in your resolver. This may solve your issue